# Change language contain in strings in xml

Tags: java, android

Here is my code to change the language at run time . I want to change the language to hindi on button click but not converting the language!!!

```
button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.but);
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
       String language = "hi";
       Locale locale = new Locale(language);
       Locale.setDefault(locale);
       Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
       configuration.locale = locale;
       getBaseContext()
           .getResources()
           .updateConfiguration(
                configuration,
                getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics()
           );
       }
   });
}
```

Comment: I think text view is not referred not here in onClick() so i.e. why??

Comment: what does it mean 'not working'  be specific

Comment: It means that when I click on button hindi language is not displaying

Comment: Do you have a different strings file for hindi with same keys?

Comment: Yep @SrikarReddy I added with same key

Comment: Then call `recreate()` after you call `updateConfiguration()`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to restart your Activity after changing locale.